# Calculate circle center (3D) from 2 point, arc angle and plane normal

Tags: math, geometry

I need to calculate a 3D circle center point from 2 points(3D) and arc angle (plane normal is also known).

I searched it with Google but I think my English is not good enough to search properly. Anyone know the calculations to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have points `A, B`, normal `N`, angle `Fi`.

Calculate difference vector (arc chord) and middle point

```
AB = B - A
M = (A + B) / 2
```

[image]

Calculate vector `F` perpendicular to `AB` and `N` using vector product and normalize it

```
F = AB x N
uF = F / len(F)
```

We know that circle center `C` lies on the ray from point `M` with direction `F` (with parameter `t` equal to apothem `CM` length (center-chord distance))

```
C = M + t * uF
```

What should be `t` value? We can express `t` through right triangle `AMC` parameters

```
 tan(Fi/2) = 0.5*len(AB) / t
```

So finally center is

```
C = M + uF * 0.5*len(AB) / tan(Fi/2)
```

Note that center `C` is not unique because we don't know arc direction (just change sign before `uF` in the last formula and get mirror point `C'` against chord)

Comment: `AB = A - B` You got that backwards. It should be `AB = B - A`.

Comment: @Stef Strictly speaking - yes, but it is not so important here

Comment: Thx. This exactly what I search for. Plus there are no gray zone for me. I understood whole logic.